# How to determine browser type (IE, FF, Chrome, etc.)

Tags: watir, firewatir, watir-webdriver

I'm in the process of switching my Watir / FireWatir scripts over to use watir-webdriver and need a means in watir-webdriver to determine which type of browser the test is currently being executed against, (IE, FF, Chrome).

With Watir / FireWatir looking at the class of the browser would return either "Watir::IE" or "FireWatir:Firefox". Using that the code could be branched to execute browser specific code.

In watir-webdriver, the class of the browser is always "Watir::Browser", it doesn't vary when running IE, Firefox, or Chrome.

#### Does anyone know of a way in Ruby with watir-web-driver to identify the browser's type (i.e. IE, Firefox, Chrome)?

#### For example: With Watir / Firewatir define methods:

```
def is_ie?()

    return self.class.to_s == "Watir::IE"

end


def is_firefox?()

    return self.class.to_s == "FireWatir::Firefox"

end
```

#### Then invoke them like this...

```
if(browser.is_ie?)

   # run the IE specific code

end


if(browser.is_firefox?)

  # run the firefox specific code

end
```

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Answer (score 10):

Try

browser.driver.browser #=> :firefox

Comment: ^ that link is broken and links to malware

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that is just what I needed!

As I'm in a transition with some scripts ported over to Watir-WebDriver and some still needing to run under Watir / Firewatir I've updated mt method as follows, posting them in case someone else is in the same situation.

def is_chrome?()

```
if(is_webdriver? == true)
  return (self.driver.browser.to_s.downcase == "chrome")
else
    return (self.class.to_s == "ChromeWatir::Browser")
end
```

end

def is_firefox?()

```
if(is_webdriver? == true)
  return (self.driver.browser.to_s.downcase == "firefox")
else
    return (self.class.to_s == "FireWatir::Firefox")
end
```

end

def is_ie?()

```
if(is_webdriver? == true)
  return (self.driver.browser.to_s.downcase == "internet_explorer")
else
    return (self.class.to_s == "Watir::IE")
end
```

end

def is_webdriver?()

```
  if($LOADED_FEATURES.to_s =~/watir-webdriver/)
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
```

end

Comment: You should mark Jarib's answer above as answering your question then